# How to bring QtWidget in front of other QtWIdget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwidgets

I have three independent QtWidget, there is parent child relation between them. I am displaying them in below order.

```
firstWidget.show();
SecondtWidget.show();
ThirdWidget.show();
```

In second widget I am loading a jar which is basically a black screen. So sometimes due to slowness in the system jar takes time to load which causes thirdwidget to go behind to the second widget.

Is there any way in Qt where no matter what is the order of showing the Widgets, a particular widget in my case thirdWidget is always on top.

I have already tried raise, activateWidow, setFocus, requestActiveWindow, SetWindowState and Window flags but nothing seems to work in my case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice. Hard to say without whether it can work or why not...

Comment: It's also good to keep in mind that `QWidgets` within the same parent are given the most priority the later they are added. The last added widget will be on top of its predecessors by default if you don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

is kind of hard because you dont get the info when the jar loading process is done

but supposing you know that, then you can bring a widget to the top by [raising](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) it :)

from the doc:

> After this call the widget will be visually in front of any overlapping sibling widgets.

which is actually what you need...
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have tried but the widgets that I am having are independent they are not siblings so this property doesn't seem to work. And jar loading process doesn't have a definite time, that's why the problem happened in first place.